# From within a JQuery change(...) event, how can I get the name of the bound Knockout field?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a series of fields in a Knockout view model that have a JQuery change event assigned to them.  Simply put, from within the change event, how can I get the name of the field that's assigned to the `input` object?  Here's a general code stub of what I'm talking about.

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: myCollection>
  <input type=text data-bind="value: field1" />
  <input type=text data-bind="value: field2" />
</div>
```

**JS Init**

```
//Get a group of JQuery elements in var $elements
$elements.each(function (idx, ele) {
  (ele).change(function (e) {
    //Using Knockout, how can I get the name of the field bound to the input element?  Specifically, it should be "field1" or field2".
  }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a very not-knockout-like way of doing something. What are you trying to achieve? Why are you not using a computed or subscription?

Comment: I'll leave this question, but for my needs, I just parsed the value out of the `data-bind` attribute. It works for my needs.  Quite well, actually.  I think there has to be a better way, though, and if someone posts a good answer, I'll give them the mark.

Comment: Are you looking to find the names of the properties to access their values? Why do you need "field1" and "field2"? Why can you not apply the logic inside the `myCollection` viewmodel using, for example, `field1.subscribe(...)`?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

```js
var viewModel = {
  myCollection: [{
    field1: 1,
    field2: 2,
    field3: 3,
    field4: 4
  }],
  field: ko.observable()
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

$('input').each((idx, ele) => {
  $(ele).change(e => {
    var context = ko.contextFor(e.currentTarget)
    context.$root.field((Object.entries(context.$data)[$(e.currentTarget).index()][0]))
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: myCollection">
  <input type=text data-bind="value: field1" />
  <input type=text data-bind="value: field2" />
  <input type=text data-bind="value: field3" />
  <input type=text data-bind="value: field4" />
</div>

<p>Change any value and change the focus to see the result</p>

<div style="margin-top: 20px; font-size: 20px;" data-bind="text: field"></div>
```

The idea is to utilize [ko.contextFor](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html) and all the good things that it comes with. We get the context and from it the $data. From the $data we do [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and from there we key on the current element index and the 0 value to get the actual key.

**Update:**

Since there was a concern about the order of the object here is another way to do it but with jQuery and regular expression (which I am sure could be shorter):

```js
var viewModel = {
  myCollection: [{
    field1: 4,
    field2: 2,
    field3: 3,
    field4: 1
  }],
  field: ko.observable()
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

$('input').each((idx, ele) => {
  $(ele).change(e => {
    var context = ko.contextFor(e.currentTarget)
    var regEx = new RegExp(/value:\s(.*?)([^,"]+)/)
    var results = regEx.exec($(e.currentTarget).data().bind)
    if (results.length >= 2)
      context.$root.field(results[2])
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: myCollection">
  <input type=text data-bind="value: field2" />
  <input type=text data-bind="value: field4" />
  <input type=text data-bind="value: field1" />
  <input type=text data-bind="value: field3" />
</div>

<div data-bind="text: field"></div>
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that this approach only works if the order of your bindings matches the order in which you define your properties on the object.

Comment: @Akrion, I'd give you the mark but as user3297291 mentions, these values aren't in order.  If his comments are correct, this wont work.  Thanks though.  This solution is close and certainly might help some.

Comment: Might be worth nothing that this was a good point. I added another way to do this with only jQuery.

Comment: Knockout [exposes its own RegExp based utils](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/expressionRewriting.js). I'd suggest using those so you can be sure you're logging the same value knockout uses under the hood. Here's a one liner you can try inside your change callback: `ko.expressionRewriting.parseObjectLiteral(ele.getAttribute("data-bind")).find(({ key, value }) => key === "value").value;` (still needs some `undefined` checks...)